# OpenNETCF.Net.Ftp.FTPWebResponse(): NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, ftp, compact-framework, opennetcf

I have some problem when use Compact Framework and OpenNETCF.Net.Ftp lib

I upload file to open ftp (test serv in web) and try to connect to ftp and read data, but have exception.
For example ftp://ftp.asu.ru/
Maybe who is know what my problem???
My code and screenshots:

```
//I use any open ftp and any file for test
Uri uri = new Uri(@"ftp://ftp.asu.ru/incoming/01/WebApp.zip");
FtpRequestCreator creator = new FtpRequestCreator();
FtpWebRequest.RegisterPrefix("ftp:", creator);
//right here, when create object, i think that i have a some problem - scr one
FtpWebRequest fwr = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
fwr.Passive = true; 

try
 {
 using (
 //Exception to here - scr 2, 3
 FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)fwr.GetResponse())
 ...
```

Stack trace:

```
 Exception NullReferenceException: at
 OpenNETCF.Net.Ftp.FtpWebRequest.SendCommand(String method, String parameter) at 
 OpenNETCF.Net.Ftp.FtpWebRequest.OpenPassiveDataConnection() at 
 OpenNETCF.Net.Ftp.FtpWebRequest.OpenDataConnection() at 
 OpenNETCF.Net.Ftp.FtpWebRequest.GetResponse() at 
 WmAutoUpdate.TransferManager.downloadFile(String url, Stream& s, String path, TransferProgress del) at 
 WmAutoUpdate.Updater.CheckForNewVersion() at 
 WmAutoUpdateExample.Program.Main()
```

I dont have reputation and u can see all image to here
http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-net/thread1277137.html

Comment: Please add the full exception trace. Many times this contains vital information regarding your problem.

Comment: it is Stack of Exception
NullReferenceException:
   at OpenNETCF.Net.Ftp.FtpWebRequest.SendCommand(String method, String parameter)
   at OpenNETCF.Net.Ftp.FtpWebRequest.OpenPassiveDataConnection()
   at OpenNETCF.Net.Ftp.FtpWebRequest.OpenDataConnection()
   at OpenNETCF.Net.Ftp.FtpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at WmAutoUpdate.TransferManager.downloadFile(String url, Stream& s, String path, TransferProgress del)
   at WmAutoUpdate.Updater.CheckForNewVersion()
   at WmAutoUpdateExample.Program.Main()

Comment: Edit your post to include the exception trace, not post as comment.

Comment: nobody dont know, what is my problem??((